# Upgraded Flutter and now I can no longer run fluter on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

I had problems with emulators that would not run the code of the example app (the emulator runed the base initial program and ignored my code, most of the time), I thought i should upgrade my configs.

After I done that, I can no longer run anything, here are the errors I have:

```
===== CRASH =====
ExceptionCode=-1073741819, ExceptionFlags=0, ExceptionAddress=00007FF7FD1D9CBC
version=2.18.6 (stable) (Tue Dec 13 21:15:14 2022 +0000) on "windows_x64"
pid=3564, thread=6072, isolate_group=main(0000012E6F3852E0), isolate=main(0000012E6F387E50)
isolate_instructions=12e6e610000, vm_instructions=7ff7fd0c66e0
Stack dump aborted because GetAndValidateThreadStackBounds failed.


===== CRASH =====
ExceptionCode=-1073741819, ExceptionFlags=0, ExceptionAddress=00007FF7FD1D9CBC
version=2.18.6 (stable) (Tue Dec 13 21:15:14 2022 +0000) on "windows_x64"
pid=17840, thread=19176, isolate_group=main(000001C77D8E5A60), isolate=main(000001C77D8F9330)
isolate_instructions=1c77cc70000, vm_instructions=7ff7fd0c66e0
Stack dump aborted because GetAndValidateThreadStackBounds failed.



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'E:\flutter_windows_3.3.10-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

All I want is to be able to run the code without errors, then care again about making it run on the emulator, any help?

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the problem,

I was trying to run an old project (the deault untitled project when you start a flutter project) after having uupgraded my versions of flutter.

The solution was to open a NEW flutter project, it had all the dependencies and versions automatically set up correctly somehow.

Thanks